# Where are Flink Job Manager and Task Manager hosted locally?

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus

I have Flink server running locally on port 8081. And I deploy jar of my flink application on it, which runs successfully.

Now I need to listen to Flink metrics from prometheus, for which I need to configure Job manager and Task manager as targets in prometheus.yml.

So where do I get ports for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configure the file `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` only on the host that you JM is placed and point the IPs of the TM as targets. In my example the JM is at `localhost` and the TM are in `localhost`, `192.168.56.101`, `192.168.56.102`, and `192.168.56.103`.

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'flink'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9250', 'localhost:9251', '192.168.56.101:9250', '192.168.56.102:9250', '192.168.56.103:9250']
    metrics_path: /
```

you have to configure the file `conf/flink-conf.yaml` to export data to Prometheus on a range of ports. This [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#prometheus-orgapacheflinkmetricsprometheusprometheusreporter) explains in detail.

```
# Metrics Reporter
metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
metrics.reporter.prom.host: 127.0.0.1
metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9250-9260
```

Comment: So how to know which ports are my JM and TM running on?For me everything is local. Flink server is local, running at 8081. But I don't know which ports JM and TM are hosted.

Comment: I updated the answer. basically you configure those ports on the `conf/flink-conf.yaml` file